# Yii2 Advanced Template

Tags: php, templates, yii2

I have installed and configured the yii2 advanced template. Everyone is saying that they want to separate frontend login from backend login, but I want to do the opposite.

What i want is, when I login to frontend, i should also remain logged in on backend side. I tried different configurations but when I login to frontend and go to backend area I'm a guest!

frontend: photography.dev
backend: admin.photography.dev

By default everyone says that yii2 advanced template has the same login for both: frontend and backend, but in my case it isn't true.

EDIT: Updated with complete backend, frontend and common configs

Common:

```
return [
'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
],
];
```

Backend:

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
```

);

```
return [
'id' => 'app-backend',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'modules' => [],
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'enableSession' => true,
        'idParam' => '_user',
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_user',
            'path'=>'/'
        ]
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '/' => 'site/index',
            '<alias:login|logout|about|contact>' => 'site/<alias>'
        ]
    ],
    'urlManagerFrontEnd' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        'baseUrl' => 'http://photography.dev',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],
],
'params' => $params,
];
```

Backend environment dev:

```
$config = [
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
        'cookieValidationKey' => '',
    ],
],
];
```

Frontend:

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php'));

return [
'id' => 'app-frontend',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'enableSession' => true,
        'idParam' => '_user',
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_user',
            'path'=>'/'
        ]
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '/' => 'site/index',
            'index' => 'site/index',
            '<alias:login|logout|about|contact|index>' => 'site/<alias>'
        ],
    ],
    'urlManagerBackend' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        'baseUrl' => 'http://admin.photography.dev',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],
],
'params' => $params,
];
```

Frontend dev environment:

```
$config = [
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'iGk90GAbgQg2jT5aQ5PMcG1A3A9E_iNq',
    ],
],
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the cookie uses the same settings in both the frontend as the backend part. Because your admin section is located in a subdomain and Yii takes that as the default domain value, you should also set the domain setting, like as follows:

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    'identityCookie' => [
        'name'     => '_identity',
        'path'     => '/',
        'httpOnly' => true,
        'domain'   => 'photography.dev',
    ],
],
'session' => [
    'name' => 'PHPFRONTENDBACKENDSESSID',
    'cookieParams' => [
        'httpOnly' => true,
        'path'     => '/',
        'domain'   => 'photography.dev',
    ],
],
```

The browser will always use the most specific cookie, so a cookie on admin.photography.dev would overrule a cookie on photography.dev

Edit: if you want to change the csrf cookie as well, you can use this in frontend/config/main.php and backend/config/main.php:

```
'request' => [
    'baseUrl'    => '',
    'csrfParam'  => '_csrf',
    'csrfCookie' => [
        'httpOnly' => true,
        'path'     => '/',
        'domain'   => 'photography.dev',
    ],
],
```

If you do this, make sure that the cookieValidationKey in frontend/config/main-local.php and backend/config/main-local.php are the same.

Comment: Even with specifying that you want your admin cookie on photography.dev? There is no other config overruling that?

Comment: I discovered something: when I opened developer tools and go to Resources - Cookies I found this:

**admin.photography.dev** is the name of the cookie when I go to http://admin.photography.dev

**photography.dev** is the name of the cookie when I go to http://photography.dev

So changing the cookieParams for the session component, all it does is adding PHPFRONTENDBACKENDSESSID to both, "admin.photography.dev" and "photography.dev" cookies, with domain 'photography.dev'.

Comment: I checked and there is no other config overruling it. I also added the same cookie validation key for both frontend and backend. It adds the PHPFRONTENDBACKENDSESSID cookie to both domains, nothing more. I can't even login anymore, when I login, it redirects to homepage and then I'm guest again. Same for both apps (frontend, backend)

Comment: Can you provide all your frontend, backend and common config so I can try to reproduce the issue? I completed my user config so it also has the identityClass and autoLogin now. This works for me by just changing the user and session config, no need to change the csrf config. After login I have PHPFRONTENDBACKENDSESSID, _identity (both on the domain photography.dev) and _csrf.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I updated the config files. I thought I will try to use photography.dev/admin for the admin side, so it should work, because it's the same domain, instead of using admin.photography.dev

Comment: You still need to complete your user and session config with the values I supplied in both frontend and backend. If you don't define the domain in the identityCookie config, it will take the full current hostname by default, which we want to avoid here.

Comment: @florinmtsc did you get this working or do you need any further help?

Comment: Sorry for this late response, I gave up on it for a while. I kept developing ignoring it.

Thank you very much, it worked like a charm. I have one more question, so I digest this better: Where are the credentials kept, so where does yii sets/gets the user to/from ? It's kept hashed in a session or cookie ?

Comment: Yii2 is still quite new to me, so I can't answer that right now, sorry. Maybe start a new question to draw people's attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the same session name for both applications for the login to apply to both applications.

Comment: The same session name won't do it. Every app (frontend, backend) has its sess id. For example, backend has a session named _backendSESSID and frontend _frontendSESSID, or something similar, different by the one I enter in config. I don't really know which session is used for login. If anyone could explain the process and how the login works in yii, please?